# Error a personalizar un marker de google maps

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, apigoogle

Defino asi el marker con un vector asset sacado de la libreria del propio Android Studio.

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
               .position(agentepos)
               .title("Agente " + agentes.getMovil())
               .snippet(PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(agentes.getMovil()))
               .snippet(agentes.getMovil())
               .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_delivery_truck)));
```

Y me da este error:

> com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.b: Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap. 
>   Que afecta directamente a esta linea de codigo.

Si utilizo el marker por defecto funciona correctamente. Posibles soluciones porfavor?

**Update:** Si utilizo un .png funciona sin problemas

Comment: ic_delivery_truck es un .xml, vector asset? o es una imagen ?

Comment: podrias revisar esto

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365658/custom-marker-in-google-maps-in-android-with-vector-asset-icon

Comment: @Axel Telkamper revisa el enlace que te sugirieron, ahí esta la respuesta que buscas.

Comment: Si se trata de un vector, cosa que no has confirmado, actualmente es imposible usar un vector como marcador. [Ha sido reportado como un bug](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/KpAN0-o_5ns;context-place=topicsearchin/maps/category$3Agmm%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false) ..., y [le puedes dar seguimiento aquí](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827905). El reporte es de 2015 y no parece que tengan mucha prisa en resolverlo.